# Proper way of declaring an array

Tags: java, arrays

I've seen that arrays work when you declare them like this:

```
int[] myarray = {2,4,6,8,10}; //Notice the brackets are with the type
```

And when you declare them like this:

```
int myarray[] = {2,4,6,8,10}; //Here the brackets are with the array name
```

So which one is the correct way of declaring an array and what are the differences (if any) between the 1st and the 2nd.

Thanks.

Comment: Both are equivalent. I would prefer first over second.

Comment: They're the same. Those accustomed to C prefer the latter.

Answer (score 5):

There is no functional difference at all. It is however considered good practice to put the brackets with the type:

```
int[] myarray = {2,4,6,8,10};
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference but [prefer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) the first declaration.

> You can also place the brackets after the array's name:
>
> `// this form is discouraged`
>     `float anArrayOfFloats[];`
>
> However,
>   convention **discourages** this form; the brackets identify the array type
>   and should appear **with** the type designation.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare an int, a one-, and a two-dimensional array, all within a single declaration:

```
int i, oneD[], twoD[][];
```

Apart from this use case, you should prefer the early placement of brackets, although both are *correct* as far as Java specification is concerned.

Comment: While it is correct in the sense that it compiles, this type of declaration violates the [official java coding conventions, section 6.1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141270.html#2992).

Comment: @Alderath Although they are (mostly) right about this one, that particular publication contains a lot of recommendations which nobody in their right mind follows. Such as declaring all your local variables at the top of the method, K&R C-style.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. It's just a [`Syntactic sugar`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) in array declaration.

Less confusing is the first type, probably.

Answer (score 1):

They are identical in effect.

The alternate declaration of `int myArray[]` is a throwback to C, but the type is `int[]`, so the first version `int[] myArray` is preferrred.